# Big O of this function logn + log((n^3) + 1)

Tags: asymptotics

I did max(logn , log((n^3) + 1) ) = O(log((n^3) +1)).

May I get verification is correct or not?

log(n^3) is a worser algorithm than logn because n^3 grows faster than n.

Comment: You're missing the fact that $\log (n^3)=3\log n$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Which is worse than $\log n$. ;) (The question/answer is so vague that there is little to say about it.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Oh, dang it. I keep forgetting about that. Thanks! I see it now!